# Getting always an error while using Jquery Ajax Post Method in C# MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I am trying to use ajax in my view in order to update changes in users profiles. Unfortunately, whatever I try, I get the error message "Error!!!". I think the problem is my model, and I have tried to customize it, but it still does not work.

Here is the JS that is executed when the user pushes the "save" button:

```
$(document.getElementById('save')).on("click", function() {
            var liSportMotives = $('#sortable li').map(function(i, n) {
                return $(n).attr('id');
            }).get();
            var liActivities = $('#myCarousel div').map(function(i, n) {
                if ($(n).hasClass('thumbnailActive')) {
                    return $(n).attr('id');
                }
            }).get();
            var myPostJSONObject = {
            Weight : parseFloat($(document.getElementById('weightrange')).val()).toFixed(1),
            Height : parseFloat($(document.getElementById('heightrange')).val()).toFixed(2),
            IsSportsBeginnerPractise : $("input:radio[name='IsSportsBeginnerPractise']:checked").val(),
            IsSportsBeginnerKnowledge : $("input:radio[name='IsSportsBeginnerKnowledge']:checked").val(),
            IsNutritionBeginnerPractise : $("input:radio[name='IsNutritionBeginnerPractise']:checked").val(),
            IsNutritionBeginnerKnowledge : $("input:radio[name='IsNutritionBeginnerKnowledge']:checked").val(),
            NewSportMotives : liSportMotives,
            NewActivities : liActivities
        };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ManageConfirmation", "Account")',
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(myPostJSONObject),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success!");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error!!!");
                }
            });
        });
```

My model in my controller looks like this:

```
public class ManageUserDetails
        {
            public decimal Height { get; set; }

            public decimal Weight { get; set; }

            public bool IsSportsBeginnerPractise { get; set; }

            public bool IsSportsBeginnerKnowledge { get; set; }

            public bool IsNutritionBeginnerPractise { get; set; }

            public bool IsNutritionBeginnerKnowledge { get; set; }

            public String[] NewSportMotives { get; set; }

            public String[] NewActivities { get; set; }
        }
```

And I have an action that looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult ManageConfirmation(ManageUserDetails model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: did you mark your Action with [HttpPost] attribute?

Comment: also - at the very least add `console.log(arguments)` to your `error` method so you can see precisely what the error is in your browser console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not redirect to any in an Ajax call.
Instead use the following :

```
public ActionResult ManageConfirmation(ManageUserDetails model)
    {
        return Json(new { data = "true" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and in the Ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ManageConfirmation", "Account")',
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(myPostJSONObject),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
                    alert("Success!");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error!!!");
                }
            });
```

See the success method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `action` is attemting to redirect due to `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`.

This will result in some unexcpected issues.

You can try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ManageConfirmation(ManageUserDetails model)
{
    //do stuff e.g. save model.
    return Json(new { data = "some data to send back" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @FuchurKool: Hi, thanks is usually expressed by up-voting ;-)